If a module is a limit of two inverse systems, then the two systems are isomorphic.
The original problem comes from corollary (10.10.6), chapter 10, Volumn I, EGA.
I state it in the language of modules here for convenience.
Claim. If an $R$-module $F$ is a limit of two inverse(or projective) systems $\{F_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{G_n\}_{n \geq 1}$, where the morphisms $\phi_{m,n} : F_n \longrightarrow F_m, \psi_{m,n} : G_n \longrightarrow G_m,  m \leq n$ satisfy $\phi_{m,n}(F_n) = F_m$ and $\psi_{m,n}(G_n) = G_m$, then the two inverse systems are isomorphic.
I believe that this claim is wrong. Are there any examples?
Edit: EGA I corollary(1, 10.10.6) is correct due to (0,7.2.9).

Is that really exactly what EGA claims? And what have you tried so far in looking for an example? For example, have you thought about systems whose limit is the zero module?

No, the EGA statement uses the sheaf language. I have tried to prove the claim. But then I think the conditions are enough to prove it and it should be a false claim. I can not find an example to overthrow the claim.

@Shrugs. It is Volumn I of EGA. Chapter 10 is about formal schemes.

The claim is false already for vector spaces.
For example, one inverse system can have increasing even dimensions and the other can have increasing odd dimensions, and the inverse limits will both have dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$.
There may still be map between inverse systems that induces an isomorphism on the inverse limit though.
EDIT:
For example, define two inverse systems by projection onto the leading factors ($m\leq n$)
$$\phi_{m,n}: k^{2n} \rightarrow k^{2m} $$
$$\psi_{m,n}: k^{2n+1} \rightarrow k^{2m+1}$$
The inverse limits are both isomorphic to $\prod_\omega k$.

Can you give more details? The morphisms $\phi_{m,n}$ should be surjective.

@Functor sure I added a bit now
